# Methods for Guarding Values vs. Data?

Tags: c#, validation, design-patterns

Does anyone know of any techniques or methodologies for guarding against invalid *data* instead of invalid *values*?  I know it seems like an odd distinction, but bear with me.

A question came up recently for me about better ways to handle guarding against invalid variable values.  We're currently wrapping exceptions in a `Guard` class, but the suggestion came up to go farther and wrap those in Extensions.  In other words, this:

```
int myVar = 0;

// Basic
if (myVar < 1) throw new InvalidArgumentException("myVar cannot be less than 1");

// Guard -- wraps the above exception
Guard.AgainstValuesLessThan(1, myVar, nameof(myVar), "Value cannot be less than 1");

// Extension -- wraps the above guard
myVar.EnsureValid();
```

My problem here is that it feels like turtles all the way down -- eventually we'll decide that extensions don't work and wrap extensions with something else. In addition, extensions on primitives make it hard to identify what you're guarding against and why -- imagine the following scenario:

```
int customerId = 1;
int employeeId = 1;

// How do I write an extension method that lets me say "Guard against invalid Customer 
// IDs" and "Guard against invalid Employee IDs"?  Both are ints.  This method allows a
// guard, but with no context.
public static void EnsureValidValue(this int actual, int expected, string msg);

employeeId.EnsureValidValue(1, "Employee ID can't be less than 1");
customerId.EnsureValidValue(1, "Customer ID can't be less than 1");
```

So I'm trying to find a better way here, and that's where I am tripping up.  So far what I've landed on is that my problem is fundamentally the fact that I'm thinking of what to guard as *data* ("I need to guard against bad customer IDs") but I'm guarding *values* ("I need to make sure this integer is at least 1").

I'm not sure where to go from here.  I feel like this could be one of those "I didn't know that exists, but that helps!" cases.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what to look at?  So far I have three thoughts, and I'm not sure if one is better than the other, or if there's some way to combine them to hit what I'm aiming for:

- Code Contracts
- Some Design Pattern I'm missing
- Some other technique or trick (e.g., Attributes?  `InvokerParameterName`?)

One last note: I'm aware that ReSharper provides an Annotations library, but not everyone on my team uses ReSharper (including me), so I don't want to have to rely on it.

Comment: So, the use of these are code-contract style pre-conditions?  You want to assert a set of pre-conditions before continuing with your logic?  These are local variables you are "guarding", not fields or properties, right?  Have you looked at the (now deprecated) Code Contracts stuff and a the ComponentModel annotations?  Another thing to look at would be the MSTest Assert class (I'm more of a positive guy, I like to _Assert_ that preconditions are met, rather than _Guard_ against bad data).

Comment: You may also want to mix this in as well (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information) so that you can get some caller information in your exceptions. If it were me, there'd probably be some static class (like `AssertValid`) with methods like 'Range<T>`, `Minimum<T>`, `Maximum<T>` (where `T:IComparable`), StringLengthRange, StringLengthMinimum, StringLengthMaximum, StringPattern (a regex), etc.

Comment: What you are really looking at is a way to specialize types beyond what you can do in C#.  You want to create a `CustomerId` or an `EmployerId` type that understands the nature of being a customer or being an employer (something you can do in some languages like oCaml - see @EricLippert 's blog for examples).  But, you can't do that in C#.  You can create types like Customer and Employer and have them Assert that their IDs meet spec, but I don't think you can go further than that.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but it was what I was talking about during my comments:

```
public static class AssertValid
{

    public static void TestAssertValid()
    {
        var customerId = 0;
        AssertValid.MinimumFor(customerId, 1, nameof(customerId));

    }
    public static void RangeFor<T>(T variableValue, T min, T max, string varName,
        string message = "Variable {0} outside of range {1} to {2} in function {3}",
        [CallerMemberName] string inFunc = "") where T : IComparable
    {
        if (variableValue.CompareTo(min) < 0 || variableValue.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        {
            var msg = string.Format(message, varName, min, max, inFunc);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(varName, variableValue, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void MinimumFor<T>(T variableValue, T min, string varName,
        string message = "Variable {0} less than minimum of {1} in function {2}",
        [CallerMemberName] string inFunc = "") where T : IComparable
    {
        if (variableValue.CompareTo(min) < 0)
        {
            var msg = string.Format(message, varName, min, inFunc);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(varName, variableValue, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void MaximumFor<T>(T variableValue, T min, string varName,
        string message = "Variable {0} greater than maximum of {1} in function {2}",
        [CallerMemberName] string inFunc = "") where T : IComparable
    {
        //...
    }

    public static void StringLengthRangeFor(string variableValue, int min, int max, string varName,
        string message = "Length of string variable {0} outside of range {1} to {2} in function {3}",
        [CallerMemberName] string inFunc = "")
    {
        if (variableValue.Length < min || variableValue.Length > max)
        {
            var msg = string.Format(message, varName, min, max, inFunc);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(varName, variableValue, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void StringLengthMinFor(string variableValue, int min, int max, string varName,
        string message = "Length of string variable {0} less than {1} characters in function {2}",
        [CallerMemberName] string inFunc = "")
    {
        if (variableValue.Length < min)
        {
            var msg = string.Format(message, varName, min, inFunc);
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(varName, variableValue, msg);
        }
    }

    public static void StringLengthMaxFor(string variableValue, int max, string varName,
        string message = "Length of string variable {0} greater than {1} characters in function {2}",
        [CallerMemberName] string inFunc = "")
    {
        //...
    }

    public static void StringLengthPatternFor(string variableValue, string regexPattern, string varName,
        string message = "String variable {0} does not match acceptable pattern in function {1}",
        [CallerMemberName] string inFunc = "")
    {
        //... Use ArgumentException
    }

}
```

Then, if you have something like (in a function named `TestAssertValid`):

```
var customerId = 0;
AssertValid.MinimumFor(customerId, 1, nameof(customerId));
```

You end up with an exception like:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Variable customerId less than minimum of 1 in function TestAssertValid
Parameter name: customerId
Actual value was 0.'
```

The other thing you might want to do is make this into an instantiable class, with all the methods being instance methods.  You create an instance of the class, do all of your assertions against that instance, and, at the end, you assert that everything is good.  If it isn't, you spit out all the failures together (in a single exception).

That way, all your tests are done before the exception is thrown.

Comment: This is very close to what I have in mind when reading the question. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think some OOP/Design patterns would be the best approach from a maintainability standpoint. I agree with you, if not all developers are required to use ReSharper, then try to embed it in the code.

The way you have your Guard clause is simple and easily reusable; I would not change that. If I understand you correctly, you are guarding against business rules, not necessarily basic values. You want to encapsulate your business rule of "Cannot have an ID less than 1", which is definitely a good rule to guard against.

A few options off the top of my head that I suggest you consider:

1. Put your logic inside the constructor of your business object. A good principle to follow is that that objects should be responsible for maintaining their own state. Pass a valid ID in the constructor and have the constructor contain the guard clause and error message such as in the snippet below.

`public Employee(int id)
{
         Guard.AgainstValuesLessThan(1, id, nameof(id), "Employee ID cannot be less than 1");
}`

If you use the object somewhere else in your code, you know for certain that it is in a valid state because you successfully constructed the object. This also solves the issue of remembering to call the Guard clause in the caller function/class.

2. Use the Decorator pattern. This one is a little more advanced and requires more setup in your project, but the idea is essentially that you could write a class that performs the validation for you. You could wire up a DI library like SimpleInjector to intercept requests that implement a certain interface (in this case, something like IEmployeeID) and perform the validation before carrying on with any code. This is very helpful for other business rules and can solve questions such as, "Does this employee ID even exist in the database?" If it doesn't exist, it can cancel any execution of the rest of your code. This way you would compartmentalize your validation logic in a separate class.

I tend to lean towards option 1 first because it helps you focus on creating objects with a valid state, which is a good principle to follow. If you need more examples or I missed the boat on your question, please let me know and I can give a better answer :)